# Kotlin MVVM how to Toast a combine message

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm using kotlin with MVVM pattern on my project.

In my viewModel I need to generate an error message and toast while input a text.

The error messages are like:

```
<string name="error_message">%s: is too long</string>
<string name="error_message1">name can't be empty</string>
```

**viewModel.kt**

```
func checkInput(context: Context, text: String) {
    if (text.isEmpty()) {
       Toast.make(context.getString(R.string.error_message1).show()
    }
    if (text.length > 10) {
         Toast.make(String.format(context.getString(R.string.error_message1), maxNumber).show()
    }
}
```

In the way above it works. But in my knowledge viewModel shouldn't hold any Android UI stuff that is `context` shouldn't be there. (Correct me if I'm wrong)

If there are no combine strings with variable, then I can `return Int`, that is return `R.string.xxx` directly. But now I don't know the proper way to do it.

I know subclass `AndroidViewModel` then I don't needs to care about context. I don't want to use this way. Because I needs localized my app with Activity's context, I think application context can't achieve it.

How to deal with this situation? thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You have to generate an event type which you need to listen to your ui component (Activity/Fragment) from there you need to display error msg or toast.

only logic part will be remain in ViewModel and display related work goes to ui component.

To achieve this try using Sealed class for this.

```
sealed class ScreenState {
    object Loading : ScreenState()
    object Success: ScreenState()
    object showToast(var type: String) : ScreenState()
}
```

wrap this inside live data

```
private val _screenState = MutableLiveData<ScreenState?>()
val screenStateLiveData: LiveData<ScreenState?> = _screenState
```

inside your ViewModel

```
 func checkInput(text: String) {
        if (text.isEmpty()) {
           _screenState.postvalue(ScreenState.showToast("1"))
        }
        if (text.length > 10) {
           _screenState.postvalue(ScreenState.showToast("2"))
        }
    }
```

observe the liveData screenStateLiveData in your ui component and display error based on your showToast() type.

```
private fun observeScreenStateData() {
        mViewModel.screenStateLiveData.observe(mContext as FragmentActivity, Observer {
            it?.let {
                when (it) {
                    is LiveTvData.Loading -> {}
                    is LiveTvData.Success ->. {}
                    is LiveTvData.showToast -> displayErrorMsg(it.type)
            }
       
})
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, I think it's the same as observe Int type like `R.string.xxx` in your way. But you do give me a hint, `sealed classes` can pass parameters. Let me vote yours, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

First of all why do you need to place `checkInput()` in `ViewModel`? You get the final string from the view which is the Activity/Fragment class validate the string and then store it `ViewModel`.

You can just move your `checkInput()` to the Activity/Fragment class and validate from there. You can also do the other way around (Store in viewmodel -> Observe from the Activity/Fragment-> then )

> But in my knowledge viewModel shouldn't hold any Android UI stuff
> that is context shouldn't be there. (Correct me if I'm wrong)

You are right here! For more understanding of why refer [here](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/viewmodels-and-livedata-patterns-antipatterns-21efaef74a54) and [here](https://www.techyourchance.com/you-dont-need-android-viewmodel/)

Comment: You are right from some point I think. If I break the `checkInput()` into multiple methods and return if pass or not. That makes the view has a lot `if and else branches` if my view has many inputs. Then it breaks MVVM. because the if else belongs to the logic shouldn't be in view. Even it's acceptable, then that much conditions check looks ugly too. If the viewModel just do the check the view just shows the result should be the best solution in my point of view. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @Ankit 's answer, it give me the hint, `sealed interface` is the workaround, that is very like `enum` in swift, that can pass parameter.

```
sealed interface ValidateError {
    data class NormalError(val resId: Int): ValidateError
    data class ParameterError(val resId: Int, val parameter: Any): ValidateError
}
```

Then in view:

```
when (it) {
        is ValidateError.NormalError -> Toast.make(it.resourceId).show()
        is ValidateError.ParameterError -> { 
                        showToast(String.format(getString(it.resourceId), it.parameter))
    }
}
```